# How to use MuPDF library to make a Mac application for viewing XPS documents?

Tags: macos, xps, mupdf

I need to make a Mac application to view XPS documents on Mac. I know that MuPDF is able to render XPS documents . I searched extensively on the web about using MuPDF library to make a mac application for viewing XPS. But I got no any idea to start . I also did not find any proper documentation for such. I found a sample project for iOS that can do the same but it is not building. I would be grateful if anyone could help me out ! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm able to build the mupdf iOS project by cloning the main mupdf git repo, running git submodule update --init, opening platform/ios/MuPDF.xcodeproj and building as normal.

If that doesn't work for you, can you edit your question to include the exact error message?

I am not aware of an mupdf example for Mac OS X, however you should be able to follow the iOS MuPageViewNormal.m code and do something fairly similar, probably using NSScrollView. If you're only trying to display XPS then you won't need to worry about all the code to do with annotations etc.

(The standard x11 mupdf can be built for Mac OS X, but this isn't a native Mac app so is unlikely to help you.)

Comment: And there was another problem that I am facing while trying to build main mupdf git repo. I am getting code signing issues. I tried all possible solutions but I am still getting that. Why is it so ?

Comment: The code signing for iOS mupdf is the standard iOS code signing. I suggesting googling for the exact error you're getting, but if you've tried that and it's still not working I suggestion asking a new question and including the full error message etc.

Comment: I am getting this issue "No code signing identites found: No valid signing identities (i.e. certificate and private key pair) matching the team ID “7M9658FA5G” were found.
CodeSign error: code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 7.1'" ....... I tried fixing this by assigning "No Code Signing" from build settings... still the problem persist.... I will be grateful for the help  !

Comment: @user3556571 In xcode, click on the project in the left bar, then the mupdf target, then in the 'Team' drop down, change that to either 'None' or to your account name. Note that it sounds like you're building for an iOS device, so you must have a paid iOS developer account and your private keys setup - if not, try building for the simulator instead.